# What is an array right after a variable called in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-operator

I'm curious about this line and have never seen this format with an array right after the variable:

`pics[coinToss() === 'heads' ? 'kitty' : 'doggy']` to render pics.doggy or pics.kitty

Is there specific documentation about this format I can read more about?

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function coinToss () {
  // Randomly return either 'heads' or 'tails'.
  return Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'heads' : 'tails';
}

const pics = {
  kitty: 'https://content.codecademy.com/courses/React/react_photo-kitty.jpg',
  doggy: 'https://content.codecademy.com/courses/React/react_photo-puppy.jpeg'
};

const img = <img src={pics[coinToss() === 'heads' ? 'kitty' : 'doggy']} />;

ReactDOM.render(
    img, 
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an array, it's a [property access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) - like when you access some array's elements with `myArray[5]` to get the 6th element (which is property `5` of the array), but it works the same for string properties of objects:
`pics['kitty']` is the same as `pics.kitty`.

The name of the property accessed is whatever `coinToss() == 'heads' ? 'kitty' : 'doggy'` evaluates to (which uses `?:` to yield either `'kitty'` or `'doggy'` depending on the result of `coinToss()`).

Here it's functionally the same as `coinToss() === 'heads' ? pics.kitty : pics.doggy`.